# Simplest possible app with online data, (android)

Tags: android, database, cloud

Forgive if this question is too basic. I am not really new to Android apps but i'm sort of new to apps "with online data".

The concept is really simple:
An Android app that allows users to view data (just text tips) that the developers regularly create/send/upload. These tips should be available for consultation 24/7.

What is the simplest possible way to do this?

Is it necessary a database? Or some cloud service? Or is there a simpler way than that?
If a database or cloud is necessary, what's the simplest solution for creating one?

Thank you for your help.

EDIT: Could I use a Dropbox or GoogleDrive account to maintain a small database? How can an Android app access it?

Comment: I can easily recommend https://firebase.google.com for this type of application.

Comment: I agree on using firebase. It will the the cheapest and easiest platform to use for your backend.

Comment: Thanks. I've heard about it but was hoping for a simpler/free solution. Where do you recommend I start learning firebase for my specific needs?

Comment: Does firebase have a UI for the developer side to regularly upload the tips?

Comment: Just like everyone recommended... FireBase and AWS are good options to implement. Another popular one is to create your own database on your computer, have PHP interact with that database and get your Android app to communicate with the PHP code [Create Login with PHP and MySQL using Volley Library](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CafH-TExDX8)

Comment: Nero, that would require my computer to be always on, right? What about using a dropbox or google drive account? Is there an API that I could use? Would it be simple?